Do subcollections avoid listener scaling problems that collections have?
The Firestore documentation says to avoid this pattern in using efficient listeners:

As the write rates for your database increase, Firestore splits the
data processing across many servers. Firestore's sharding algorithm
tries to co-locate data from the same collection or collection group
onto the same changelog server. The system tries to maximize the
possible write throughput while keeping the number of servers involved
in the processing of a query as low as possible.
However, certain patterns might still lead to suboptimal behavior for
snapshot listeners. For example, if your app stores most of its data
in one large collection, the listener might need to connect to many
server to receive all data it needs. This remains true even if you
apply a query filter. Connecting to many servers increases the risk of
slower responses.
To avoid these slower responses, design your schema and app so that
the system can serve listeners without going to many different
servers. It might work best to break your data into smaller
collections with smaller write rates.

This means you should avoid having one large collection that many listeners connect to because it may lead to slower responses.
A different Firestore documentation gives this example of a how to build a chat app. The example has a structure where messages are stored in a subcollection called messages like this: rooms/roomA/messages/message1. The pattern is collection/document/collection/document.
Question: Does the fact that messages is a subcollection (and not a collection) avoid the scaling problem listed in using efficient listeners?
EDIT 1
For example, userA would create a listener that listens to the path rooms/roomA/messages while another userB would be listening to the path rooms/roomB/messages. If there are a lot of documents in the path rooms/roomA/messages for userA but not many in rooms/roomB/messages for userB, would userB experience slower response times? Or would the two user experiences be independent of each other?
EDIT 2
It looks like if you create a listener that listens to messages as a whole, you will have the scaling problem.
However, in the example above, if you are listening to rooms/roomB/messages you will not have an issue because it is indexed differently.

No, there is no difference between querying a large collection or a large subcollection.  They are both going to behave identically in terms of cost and performance.  It's the total size of the documents in the collection or subcollection that matters.  That's why you're given the advice "It might work best to break your data into smaller collections with smaller write rates."

I added an example to my question. Would what you said still apply to that scenario?

You're describing a different situation from your original question.  Subcollections don't affect each other. They're indexed independently.

My intention with my original question was to describe the scenario in my example. I must have done a poor job though. Would you mind updating your answer to reflect the answer in your comment so I can accept it?

Your question still asks "Does the fact that messages is a subcollection (and not a collection) avoid the scaling problem listed in using efficient listeners?"  That's what my answer addresses.  If you have a different question, I think you should post it separately for a separate answer.

Fair enough. I was just trying to make it easier for someone who stumbles across this question because they may have the same misunderstanding I did. I will add some more context to my question.
